# How to compress h265 video using ffmpeg h265?

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, compression, h.264, hevc

I am using my camera app to record some videos. Before they only had h264 option so the file sizes very huge like 10GB for 1hour for standard smartphone camera quality. I was using ffmpeg to compress them and they would reduce to about 150-200MB while looking the same.

Now they added an h265 option so I used that to record in the first place. Now these files might be a bit smaller but they are still quite large like 5GB. So naturally I tried ffmpeg on these videos but not only they are much slower to compress i.e. 0.3x speed, but also the file size is maybe reduced by 5%.

So not sure what I have to do to get these new h265 videos just like the ones I encoded before using ffmpeg so that their size would be about 150-200MB.

Is it because ffmpeg can not efficiently compress h265 using h265 coded?

Comment: Well... people usually control the quality when they are encoding stuff (*expectations about the output*). Bitrate or constant rate factor for example. Not being mentioned it looks like you placed all hopes on defaults and of course things might change. [ffmpeg docs: h265 encoding](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265).

Comment: The app doesn't have any options other than resolution and codec, but I always used -crf 28 but like I mentioned in OP, the difference in size is minimal after I compress them using h265 -crf 28, and the encoding speed is so slow.

Comment: You *reencode* app-produced files to get smaller files. What does the App has to do with it? You should pass options to ffmpeg for encoding the app-encoded file to something new? And yes, it might be possible that your final crf 28 is not the right value anymore due to your changes in the pipeline. Just change it

Comment: Well I wasn't sure which settings you meant that's why I mentioned the app. I will keep experimenting then. I thought I might have to encoding in 264 and then 265 again.

Comment: That would be a bad approach. You just play with the ffmpeg crf in use to encode app-input to your new output. The slowdowns can be due to many reasons (hard to read out from whats given). If you re-encoded h264 -> h264 before, it's probably much faster than h265 -> h265. But this also depends on options. 0.3x sounds so slow, that i suspect that either the input changes in regards to resolution (would be strange) or indeed you are now encoding h265 but did not before. (The h265-decoding overhead should be smaller i guess)

Comment: Thanks I was always encoding in h265, but got the biggest size savings from h264 source files. h265 to h265 considering the speed and file savings, it doesnt seem to worth it, but I will try different settings then.

Comment: Show your command and the complete log. You can add `-t 10` option so you don't have to encode the whole thing.

Comment: @llogan: This is what I get: https://imgur.com/YdnGcK7

Comment: For next time please keep in mind that images of text are less ideal than copying and pasting text. Images are often harder to parse, needlessly take up more space, unusable in terms of accessibility, and text can't be copied from images. *I was using ffmpeg to compress them and they would reduce to about 150-200MB while looking the same.* Were you encoding the H.264 inputs to H.265? *So naturally I tried ffmpeg on these videos but not only they are much slower to compress* Same here, are you comparing encoding H.264 vs H.265?

Comment: ...your actual ffmpeg commands would make things more clear, but I can provide a guess-answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Not all formats are equal

H.265 is a newer generation format than H.264, and in ideal situations H.265 can provide significant file size savings (but it can be much slower to encode).

So it may be unfair and unrealistic to compare H.264 to H.265.

## Not all encoders are equal

Some encoders are crap no matter the format. Your H.264 input may have been created by a hardware encoder which sacrifices quality-per-bit for encoding speed. These are inefficient encoders.

So if you take a H.264 input that was made from an inefficient encoder, then re-encode it using an efficient H.265 encoder you may see significant file savings despite compression unfriendly encoding artifacts present in the source.

## Your H.265 input was created by ffmpeg

As shown in your console output: `encoder: Lavf58.34.101`, which is the libavformat library version. This library is responsible for muxing the file.

I'm not sure which encoder was used, but it could indicate that x265–an efficient encoder–could have been used. The output from `mediainfo` may indicate the actual encoder.

So if that is the case, and you re-encode it, you may not see much of a difference other than [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss).

Comment: Thanks no I am always using h265 to compress my videos.

Comment: @JoanVenge Ok, but regardless the answer is basically still the same.

Comment: I switched back to recording in h264 and wow now I see the difference. Somehow it captures too much noise in 265 or applies median filter in 264 so that's why my final compression was working really well when the source was 264.